# How remove post_type column from WP admins posts table / settings screen columns

Tags: wordpress

Ubuntu 22.04, PHP 8.1, Wordpress 6.0.1, custom theme.

In the administration panel of WP in any section (pages, posts and CPT) in the table with the list of posts I have an additional "type" column.

```
<th scope="col" id="post_type" class="manage-column column-post_type">Type</th>
```

There is no such column on the development machine [It is also not available in the list of columns in the settings to show/hide].
Source code and WP version is the same. And on the production column appears (maybe something in database?).

Admins (on production) can disable showing that column in the screen settings. But can it be removed somehow globally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure, if there any plugin that cause to add the type column, you can try to disabling each plugin one by one and check if the column getting removed.

Comment: You have right. "Post Type Switcher" plugin do that. Which is fully understandable because it is used to change the post type :)